# jquery sort multiple columns - datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable and have 10 columns in it. I need to sort three columns 2, 3 and 4. The 4th column has two **h:outputText**, one - the order no. and other being the date. I need to sort by order no. for the 4th column. How could I do this? I have added the below code but it doesn't sort properly.

```
$('[id$=example]').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
        "bAutoWidth" : false,
        "bRetrieve" : true,
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "aaSorting" : [],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0,1,5,6,7,8,9 ] }
   ]
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: may this will help you http://jsfiddle.net/vxshL3ju/1/

Comment: Show your HTML table with sample data. Consider creating an example on jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$('[id$=example]').dataTable({

                "order": [
                    [2, 'desc']
                ],
});
```

Comment: It works. Can even order by multiple columns like `order: [ [2, 'desc'], [1, 'asc'] ]`.